# Angular 7 Service Worker not Working Offline when using Node.Js Server

Tags: node.js, angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular7

I have an Angular 7 project with PWA functionality added.
I basically have all PWA-related settings set to default.

---

My issue is, that **offline mode** does not work when deploying the project to my server. It's also not working when starting the server on localhost.

However, when using the npm module `http-server` to host the app on localhost, the offline mode works.

---

Online the service worker is applied:

[image: sw]

Here is what happens when loading app offline:

[image: offline]

---

The code of my Node.Js server looks like this:

```
require('module-alias/register')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const prod = require('@root/prod')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const path = require('path')
const compression = require('compression')
app.use(compression())
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist/client')));
const api = require('@root/api/api.routes')
app.use('/api', api)
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist/client/index.html'))
})
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.log('error occured', err.stack);
    res.status(500).send({ "Error": err.stack });
});
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`• • •`)
    console.log(`• Server launched   on port`, port)
    console.log(`• Server running in ${prod ? '  production' : '  development'} mode`)
    console.log(`• • •`)
})
```

Here are all files from the production build:

[image: fiels]

Comment: Did you resolve the issue at this point? I have the same problem!

Comment: nope, sorry. I couldn't find a fix

Comment: The same issue with no solution yet! :((

Comment: Is there a solution yet? Using angular 8. Its working only with `http-server` module. No tweaks (like registering inside main.ts file) seem to work, while in another project with angular 7, we had php backend and it was working fine.